# Is there any way to install libgnome.i686, libgnomeui.i686 on CentOS 8?

Tags: centos

I tried to install some dependencies at CentOS 8 since cannot use RHEL 8 anymore.

However it doesn't seems like I can't found some dependencies for CentOS 8 which used to support from 6 and 7.

Does anyone have a method to install `libgnome.i686` and `libgnomeui.i686`?

Here is the error message what I faced when I tried to get the libs.

```
[jason@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install libgnome.i686 
Last metadata expiration check: 1:28:26 ago on Wed 23 Jun 2021 12:33:37 AM PDT. 
No match for argument: libgnome.i686 
Error: Unable to find a match: libgnome.i686**
```

I did update `yum` and `dnf` and use both `yum` and `dnf` to get it from the repositories I have.

Below are the repository I have.

```
[jason@localhost yum.repos.d]$ ls
CentOS-Linux-AppStream.repo          CentOS-Linux-FastTrack.repo         epel-modular.repo
CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo             CentOS-Linux-HighAvailability.repo  epel-playground.repo
CentOS-Linux-ContinuousRelease.repo  CentOS-Linux-Media.repo             epel.repo
CentOS-Linux-Debuginfo.repo          CentOS-Linux-Plus.repo              epel-testing-modular.repo
CentOS-Linux-Devel.repo              CentOS-Linux-PowerTools.repo        epel-testing.repo
CentOS-Linux-Extras.repo             CentOS-Linux-Sources.repo           getpagespeed-extras.repo.disabled
```

Comment: I guess it's about `libgnome-2.32.1-9.el7.i686, libgnomeui-2.24.5-8.el7.i686` ? I.e. old **gnome2** packages ? ..... Luckily the **109**! dependencies are still available in CentOS 8 repo's https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14RkibL_OpY2NxZDS_XbYQrLIebmbFx9d?usp=sharing  ...... If you want the rpms, please read README....

Answer (score 0):

If it's about `libgnome-2.32.1-9.el7.i686, libgnomeui-2.24.5-8.el7.i686` i.e. old gnome2 packages :

Luckily the ~109! dependencies are still available in CentOS 8 repo's.

CentOS 7 packages `libgnome-2, libgnomeui-2` and other old dependencies  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14RkibL_OpY2NxZDS_XbYQrLIebmbFx9d

Please read the file README-install.txt